# "Error (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action" when I POST normal user

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I would like to Post messages to my Facebook feed with C# SDK but I have this error. When I login with Admin user or Testers user or Developers users are not errors, but I login with normal user (Facebook user) then error.

> (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action.

- **My scope**: user_posts, user_birthday, user_status, user_about_me, email, user_managed_groups, user_groups, user_friends,         read_friendlists, read_insights, read_mailbox, read_stream,         publish_actions, public_profile, publish_pages,manage_pages.

Thanks you.

Comment: Has Facebook approved your use of those permissions?  If Facebook hasn't approved it yet, normal users will not have the permissions you defined and you won't see an error unless you specifically check which permissions you have within your own code.

Comment: How do I know that Facebook has approved my application or not? Thank's!

Comment: On the Facebook Developer Console (https://developers.facebook.com) go to "My Apps" then to your app.  In the left menu, go to "Status & Review".  At the bottom of the page will be a table with a list of "Approved Items".  If your permission is not in that list, it is not approved.  You will need to start a new submission for review in order to get Facebook to review and approve your permission requests.

Comment: Thanks you very much! I will try again.